# number formation as per os system

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

I am using .NET 3.5 framework with C#
My application going to use worldwide. (Windows 7, 64 bit)

I am having one double/float number which later on convert into string.
But on different OS it's changing the value like `46.57` become `46,57`

How can I stop this ? Is .NET can handle this internally ?

Below is my code;

```
Decimal lon = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[j]["lon"]);    
Decimal lat = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[j]["lat"]);    
lon = lon / 100000;    
lat = lat / 100000;    
string longitude = Convert.ToString(lon);    
string latitude = Convert.ToString(lat);
```

Comment: Because your operatings systems have different `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: How can I code so it's going to work on all OS ?

Comment: This is default behavior and in most cases, desirable (users see formats for decimal numbers and dates in formats they expect). When this is *not* helpful is when you are writing to a text file or XML file and want to make sure that the data saved in one culture is readable in a different one.

Comment: @Hardik It doesn't depends on your OS. **It depends on your operating system's current culture.** As I said in my answer, if your both operating systems have same culture, that will be no problem. Or you can set some properties to use decimal separator (_and maybe thousands separator_) in both operating systems as I said the last sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String representation of a decimal value is culture specific.

[`Convert.ToString(decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59095yyw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses current culture thread.

Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#a2693ea708a8dd53);

```
public static string ToString(decimal value)
{
     return value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Probably one of your OS uses a culture that have `.` as [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the other one uses a culture that have `,` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> How can I stop this ? is .NET can handle this internally ?

.NET can't handle this. It uses whatever it founds as a current culture.

But you can.

Using the same culture thread in your both OS can solve this issue or you can use [`CultureInfo.Clone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to clone your current culture and set your `NumberDecimalSeparator` property what ever string you want.

Answer (score 5):

As explained by others, this is default and desired behavior.

You can use the `InvariantCulture` to always output in the same format:

```
string longitude = Convert.ToString
                   ( lon
                   , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

The differences are a function of the culture on each machine/OS. I would encourage you to be more explicit with the ToString() conversion. Without those parameters you are leaving it to .NET to make the decision for you. For example:

```
string longitude = lon.ToString("G", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

You can find more examples of valid conversions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).